# SQL query grouping data not in

Tags: sql, group-by

I need a query to pull data from a table per date, where EmpID has only one code.
Here is sample data to illustrate

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.#Cars 
   (   
   File_date smalldatetime, 
   Code varchar(10), 
   EmpID varchar(10)
   ) 

   INSERT into #Cars (File_date, Code, EmpID) values ('2020-03-01', 'ABC', '1234')
   INSERT into #Cars (File_date, Code, EmpID) values ('2020-03-01', 'XYZ', '1234')

   INSERT into #Cars (File_date, Code, EmpID) values ('2020-03-02', 'ABC', '3456')
   INSERT into #Cars (File_date, Code, EmpID) values ('2020-03-02', 'XYZ', '3456')

   INSERT into #Cars (File_date, Code, EmpID) values ('2020-03-03', 'ABC', '1234')
   INSERT into #Cars (File_date, Code, EmpID) values ('2020-03-03', 'XYZ', '4444')

   INSERT into #Cars (File_date, Code, EmpID) values ('2020-03-04', 'ABC', '3456')
   INSERT into #Cars (File_date, Code, EmpID) values ('2020-03-04', 'XYZ', '1234')
```

I want records with only 'XYZ' code per date. Meaning I do not want records if they had ABC and XYZ on a particular date. 
So in above case EmpID 4444 on 2020-03-03 and EmpID 1234 on 2020-03-04.

I tried following but does not work:

```
  Select a.* 
   from #cars a 
   where EmpID not in 
    ( select EmpID from #cars where code = 'ABC')
   and code = 'XYZ'
```

please guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break this down.

First, you want all the rows from #cars that have code 'XYZ'

```
select c1.* from #cars c1
where c1.code='xyz'
```

Then you want to see if any lines have any other codes that have the same date and empid. So you left join back on the same table with the same empid and date, but different code

```
select c1.* from #cars c1
    left join #cars c2 on c1.empid=c2.empid 
                and c1.file_date=c2.file_date 
                and c1.code<> c2.code
where c1.code='xyz'
```

Since this is a left join, any matches will have a value for empid for the second table, any that don't will have null for empid for the second table.  Since we only want the ones that don't have matches for other values, we add c2.empid is null to the where clause

```
select c1.* from #cars c1
    left join #cars c2 on c1.empid=c2.empid 
                   and c1.file_date=c2.file_date and
                   c1.code<> c2.code
where c1.code='xyz' and c2.empid is null
```

Comment: can you please explain why did you put 'c2.empid is null'? It is working but not sure how

Comment: @SilverFish How's that?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `having` clause:

```
 select file_date, empid
 from #cars
 group by file_date, empid
 having min(code) = max(code) and min(code) = 'xyz';
```

If you have only two values, you can simplify this to:

```
 select file_date, empid
 from #cars
 group by file_date, empid
 having min(code) = 'xyz';
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e4b4c9a04812ae756b28228a5d1eb9e6) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @SilverFish: You know what `GROUP BY` does, but you don't know what `MIN` and `MAX` do? That's weird. You can look them up in the docs or just google them.

Comment: It is not retrieving correct results. I am looking for emp having only XYZ on particular date. In above case that would be 2020-03-03 00:00:00 XYZ 4444 and
2020-03-04 00:00:00 XYZ 1234

Comment: I have used min/max for numeric values or dates for I'm asking regards alpha codes

Comment: @SilverFish: Gordon's queries look fine. You may have to change `'xyz'` to `'XYZ'`, though. What result do you get? MIN/MAX determine the minimum and maximum (i.e. first and last) values in alphabetical order.

Comment: Please ignore alphabetic orders. This is just sample code. They could be any apha characters being used as code. I need to filter on a code which is being used for a particular EmpID on a particular date. If another one is also being used then we don't want those recs

Comment: I changed my select but it is returning only 1 record when there are 2 valid records

Comment: @SilverFish . . . I added a db<>fiddle.  Both version return two rows in the fiddle.